# upload image on server after submit in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to upload image in my form .i don't want to save image on server before submit. i want to save image on the server click on the submit button .

Comment: Perhaps this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068303/fileupload-to-filestream) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(FileUpload1.HasFile){
    string absolute_path=MapPath("~/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
    string relative_path="~/" + FileUpload1.FileName;
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(absolute_path);
    Image1.ImageUrl=relative_path;
}
```

You can use this code for uploading an image.

If you want to save after a button click then write like this

```
private void ButtonUpload_Click(object as Sender...)
{
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(absolute_path);
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply but i want to upload multiple image . using this we can only upload only one image

Comment: @pargan: do you want to upload several images?

Comment: yes alex i want to upload Three images . but on upload i also want to show image to user. after that then the user submit images and other information save on the server.

Comment: @pargan: then take a look at `Request.Files` property