# upload files to a different server

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

My web applications are on Server D. So I created a web application that has an fileupload control. I can easily upload any file to a folder (FILES) inside the web app.

My question now: How can I upload the same file (from code behind) to a folder (UPLOADS) on a different server (SERVER T) that I have? I also need to read,write and modify that file on the SERVER T. Remember that I use Web Forms and not Windows Forms!!!

Someone told me something about creating a Network Service account on server T for the web app on server D to use and give that account permissions or something like that but he doesn’t know the details either.

Is there a tutorial, guide since I'm sure there is a way to do this…

Also, all I can find on Google is using ftp but for windows forms only…

Kinda stuck around here…

Comment: Does the target server has shared folder which can be accessed by original server?

Comment: @DavidStratton That assumes the servers 'know' about each other, and I would always say this article demonstrates the way _not_ to do it; create an intermediary vector for communication, such as a service.

Comment: @Yahya, yes to you question. The 2 servers are in the same network and they can access eachother //ServerT //ServerD

Comment: @Grant Thomas, the servers do "know" each other... how would i create a service like the one you suggested. do you have a link ?

Comment: @Nathan Try this then: http://growingtech.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/copy-network-shared-folder-file-using-c.html

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @GrantThomas, While creating service to deal with manipulating files is useful suggestion at the end last server in the chain of services will have the same exact problem - file storage on one server, service talking to that is on another (if you do proper isolation). So I think [article](http://2leggedspider.wordpress.com/2007/05/28/upload-files-to-unc-share-using-asp-net/) that David Stratton linked to would give good starting point for that last segment.

Comment: @yahya thanks man that was it: the blog you gave me with the impersonation did the trick...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks Alex...your link had a second solution similar to yahya's article and it totally worked. thanks again...

Comment: @Nathan my pleasure, I will post it as an answer so it can help others in future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [this blog post](http://growingtech.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/copy-network-shared-folder-file-using-c.html)

> We can do following-
>
> 1. Login to a user account using c#
> 2. Impersonate as the logged in user
> 3. Copy the file using System.IO.File.Copy

Answer (score 2):

If you need to read/write/change files in a network folder, you can try this:

```
Open IIS > Application Pools 
            > Select Application pool of the site
              > Advanced Options
                > Process Model > Select Identity
```

Now you should know the Application Pool Account. Finally make sure that account does have the required privileges to `SERVER T\UPLOADS` folder.

Comment: Note: It is not going to work if site is using impersonation.

Comment: ? I'm sorry if my comment looked like "your answer is wrong" - all I wanted to is remind future readers that this approach may not immediately work for sites. Impersonation/"NTLM one-hop-hell" is very hard already, so being aware when some solution don't apply could be useful.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, ah,.. that is okay. Extra information always welcome !

Comment: +1 - actually this is vary safe approach to have credentials to talk to other Windows servers (assuming one need just one set of credentials - i.e. talking to single DB/file share). As I've noted - if site uses impersonation more work would be needed to revert impersoantion to run as process' account.

Comment: @Kaf In the select Identity drop down there were only 3 options: Network Service, Local Service and Local System. I chose Network Service and then i made sure that the folder has NETWORK SERVICE group/user in the security tab with full permissions. But i still get the same error in my err.Message: Access to the path '\\ServerT\Uploads\file.dbf is denied'. WHen i run this on my localhost, everything works fine though...

Comment: You can access `Uploads` folder like that only if you have shared it. Otherwise you have to access like `\\ServerT\c$\Uploads\..` where `c` is the local drive. I am not a security expert but I think you may need to share it and give full control to the network services. If not working try to use a custom user.

Comment: @Kaf Uploads is shared...as i said Everything works fine when i compile my project locally...the problem shows up when i go live with it.

Also, when i copy //serverT/Uploads/Files/file.dbf in the URL it automatically downloads it.   WHen i copy //serverT/Uploads/Files/ i can see all the files listed as well...

Comment: That means `virtual path` is working and you have allowed `directory browsing`. Can you try this using a custom account: Create a new account (or even existing one) and make a member of `IIS_IUSRS` user group in IIS running machine. Then select that user for the `Application Pool`. Next give him permission to above shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution would be to simply ftp the file to the new server, here is an example

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/343913/Simple-FTP-library-in-Csharp

or doing an http post to the other server here is a SO question with a decent answer for doing that

[FileUpload to FileStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068303/fileupload-to-filestream)

once the file is on the other server push the work of update/modify/etc to the other server