# asp.net fileupload control to upload file to different domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload

I have two websites: Website A and Website B. Is it possible to use fileupload control on website A and through which I upload the file to website B.

I have been looking for solution for some time but not found any.

I know we can access any file on website B so it's not have any access restriction.

Comment: are they on the same server?

Comment: @Prospector yes they are on the same server. all I have the ip address of two websites, it's same. And I have ftp server access with different passwords

Comment: Using credentials of websiteB and fullyqualified file path in websiteB, You can upload file.

Comment: @Raghu question is how? should I use ftp or what?

Comment: if they're on the same server then just use a server path and share it.

Comment: @Prospector how can please show how can I do it as an answer?

Comment: all you have to do is specify the path `uploadPath = "C:\\Uploads\\";` post your code if you can't figure it out and ill look it over.

Comment: @Prospector I am using webhosting. I don't have access to C. All I have is httpdocs and I copy paste files to it using ftp

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a shared web host then your options are limited, check this link

http://madskristensen.net/post/simple-ftp-file-upload-in-c-20

and check the last post in this

[upload files to a different server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528883/upload-files-to-a-different-server)