# Sending file stream through JQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

**What I want to do:**

Upload a file to autoCAD server and display a URN received from the server.

**What I am currently doing:**

Upload the file using `<asp:FileUpload>` control;

Get the uploaded file object from code behind using:`HttpPostedFile myFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;`

The code behind will return a string called `FileURN`, it will be shown in a textarea using:

`<textarea class="form-control" readonly="readonly" rows="5" id="txt_resUploadFile"><%= FileURN %></textarea>`

**The problem:**

The html page gets refreshed every time the upload button is clicked. I understand that the full page gets refreshed when a trip to server is made. So I wanted to use AJAX for that. But soon I realize AJAX calls only Webmethod, which has to be static. Since `HttpPostedFile myFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;` is no longer working in a static method, How can I get uploaded file stream?

Code Snippet:

**html:**

```
<div>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        <br/>
        <asp:Button class=" btn btn-primary col-md-2" ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload file" onclick="btnUpload_Click" />
    </div>
</form>
<textarea class="form-control" readonly="readonly" rows="5" id="txt_resUploadFile"><%= FileURN %></textarea>
```

**Codebehind:**

```
    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            HttpPostedFile myFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
            //send myFile to autoCAD server and get result from that server....
        }
    FileURN = "The Result";
```

Comment: you can try using asp.net AJAX. have a look at this http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/AjaxFileUpload-example-to-upload-multiple-files-in and this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667406/File-Upload-Control-with-ASP-NET-and-AJAX

Comment: Can you be more specific what are you trying to achieve?If you still use c# to get the stream you can follow this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068303/fileupload-to-filestream

Comment: Hi @Developer, thanks for the editing suggestion first. My ultimate goal is to to send a PUT RestRequest to autoCAD server, the requestBody Parameter carries the filestream data (in byte array) of the file I uploaded from `asp:FileUpload` control. The problem I have here is if I use C# onClick function, when the function is finished, a full page refresh will be called, which is something I don't want.

Comment: With c# onclick you cannot avoid post back.however can you use updatepanel or I think client side Ajax solution would fit nice for this case.

Comment: using(var client = new System.Net.WebClient()) {
    client.UploadData(address,"PUT",data);
}